# Javascript when to initialize an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm still learning JavaScript, but I'm missing or misunderstanding a step to take me from theory to practice.

I need an object that keeps and maintains the page state.

```
myState={
page_no=...
form_show=...
input_show=... 
}
```

The most obvious solution is to just declare it as global. 
But everywhere I turn I see - global is bad.
What is the alternative?

Comment: There's a syntax error in that declaration. when declaring objects, you use `:` rather than `=` to assign values to it's properties and separate them via `,`. Second, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little too general. The answer is "it depends". Without more context it's hard to give a more specific answer. Globals are sometimes bad, but sometimes they are the only sensible solution. If you have many globals, you should consider wrapping them up in a single object so that you have only a single global instead of a whole bunch.

Example:

```
var myModule = {
    myState : {
        page_no: 0,
        form_show: false,
        input_show: false 
    },
    someOtherGlobal: {
         someProp: "foo"
    }
    someFunction: function() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

The idea here is to limit the possibility of conflicts with other code that might be running on a page. There *might* be another `myState` somewhere, but it's less likely to be another `myModule.myState`.

Even better is if you can limit all you code to a single closure which is great if your code doesn't need to expose anything to other code.

```
(function() {
    // this only exists inside this closure
    var myState = {
        page_no: 0,
        form_show: false,
        input_show: false 
    }

    // some code that will execute inside the closure and has access to stuff inside the closure
    if (myState.page_no === 0) {
        myState.form_show = true;
    }

    // often you might hook up event handlers here
    someDomElement.onClick = function() {
        // this will have access to myState
    };
})();
```

A common way to do this is to use the doc load or doc ready events. In jQuery, people often do this:

```
$(function() {
    // all your code that will run when the DOM is ready...
});
```

And you can combine the two by having you closure return an object and assign it to a variable. Something like:

```
var myModule = (function() {
    var myState = {
        page_no: 0,
        form_show: false,
        input_show: false 
    };

    var hiddenCount = 0;     // this won't be accessible outside this closure

    var increaseCount = function() {
        hiddenCount++;       // this can access hiddenCount because it's inside the closure
        console.log(hiddenCount);
    }

    return {
        myState: myState,
        increaseCount: increaseCount
    };
})();
```

And now you can do something like:

```
myModule.myState.page_no = 1;
```

And:

```
myModule.increaseCount();     // would echo 1
```

But not:

```
myModule.hiddenCount = 3;     // hiddenCount wasn't exposed by returning it
```

Comment: The first example you show is what I have in mind for my purpose.

Comment: The more I look at it the more sense it makes. Your first example (simplest for my beginner brain) is what I was thinking of. There is some testing to do, but I think you answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Global isn't **always** bad. You just shouldn't abuse it. Anyway here is how you would write it properly to make it global (with some default values):

```
window.myState={
    page_no: 0,
    form_show: false,
    input_show: false 
}
```